# How does one install pyzmq 2.1.10 for python2.6 on window xp win32?

Tags: python, windows, zeromq

I'm trying to install pyzmq and there seems to be no working windows binarys for py2.6 at [pipy](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyzmq/2.1.10) 
Also there are none at https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/downloads. They do have a msi for pyzmq 2.1.4 but that one also does not seem to work.

Tried 
easy_install-2.6 pyzmq 
which ties to install pyzmq 2.1.10 but fails with the error

```
Fatal: ZMQ directory must be specified on Windows via setup.cfg or 'python setup.py      configure --zmq=/path/to/zeromq2'
```

error: Setup script exited with 1

---

then tied
easy_install-2.6 pyzmq configure --zmq=C:\home\installed_applications\ZeroMQ_2.1.10
and get the same error so I decide to download pyzmq-2.1.10
I cd into C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\pyzmq-2.1.10
and run
python setup.py configure --zmq==C:\home\installed_applications\ZeroMQ_2.1.10
and I get
running configure

---

Configure: Autodetecting ZMQ settings...
    Custom ZMQ dir:       C:\home\installed_applications\ZeroMQ_2.1.10
Fatal:
    Failed to run ZMQ test program.  Please check to make sure:

```
* You have a C compiler installed
* A development version of Python is installed (including header files)
* A development version of ZMQ >= 2.1.4 is installed (including header files)
* If ZMQ is not in a default location, supply the argument --zmq=<path>
* If you did recently install ZMQ to a default location,
  try rebuilding the ld cache with `sudo ldconfig`
  or specify zmq's location with `--zmq=/usr/local`
```

---

---

I also tried building it using the instructions zeromq gives here
http://www.zeromq.org/docs:windows-installations
but there seems to be gaps either in me knowing how to use the ruby installer or in the instructions.

---

Lastly I tried using a windows installer from 
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyzmq 
but that gave me the following error

> > > import zmq
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\pyzmq-2.1.10\zmq__init__.py", line 35, in 
> > >           from zmq.utils import initthreads # initialize threads
> > >       ImportError: cannot import name initthreads

I also tired installing via the link at the very bottom of http://www.zeromq.org/docs:windows-installations
linking to http://miru.hk/archive/ZeroMQ-2.1.10-win32.exe but I also get an error message.

Has anyone got this to work lib to work with python2.6? python2.7 seems to have no issues.

Actually even if you use the win installers from https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/downloads for python2.7 for zmq 2.1.10 you get the error IPython.zmq requires pyzmq >= 2.1.4, but you have 2.1.**10**. Clearly a bug in the checking of the version. The older version 2.1.7 works seems to work because the 7 passes the check since its one digit long I'm guessing.

Comment: I don't have much experience with Gohlke's installers, but if they work, they are definitely the easiest approach when there is no official version of a package.  The initthreads error is most often encountered if you try to import zmq when there is a 'zmq' folder in your current working directory. Was this the case?  As for compiling pyzmq from source, you probably need MSVC, and the version-check step will not build/run if you don't.

Comment: Was not in zmq folder. Wish it was that simple. Do you think the MSVC route is easier then MinGW?

Comment: I've only ever used MSVC, so I don't know if MinGW works.  But distutils will try to use msvc by default, so I think you have to instruct it to use mingw explicitly if you want it to use that to build extensions.

Comment: Also, the IPython version check bug was fixed in master a few months ago. It no longer does simple string comparison, but patching 0.11 to just skip it is trivial.